# Is there a function that terminates the program without waiting the child to executes?

Tags: c

The goal is to allow the child to execute for one second. If more than 1s, the program should terminate. (Certainly, if the execution takes less than 1s, it executes immediately). My current execution of the **parent branch** is shown here:

```c
int ret;

if (waitpid(pid, &ret, WNOHANG) == 0) {
    sleep(1);
    if (waitpid(pid, &ret, WNOHANG) == 0) {
        kill(pid, SIGKILL);
    }
}

if(WIFEXITED(ret) && WEXITSTATUS(ret) == 1){
    printf("*** Command not found: %s\n", args[0]);
}else{
    //print error message
}
```

However, the `waitpid()` with `WNOHANG` returns 0 whatsoever (no matter what the command is). And the program ended up always waiting for 1 second. Is there a command to replace this `waitpid()`? If not, what can I do to achieve what I want to achieve?

Comment: After the `kill`, add: `waitpid(pid,&ret,0);`

Comment: @CraigEstey after the `kill`? For commands like `ls -l`, it would still wait for 1s. Not sure how it works.

Comment: To get the `sleep` to terminate early, we need it to terminate due to a signal. The `errno` from it would be `EINTR`. To do this, we must enable a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`. We need a function: `void sighdr(int signo) { }` And, we enable it with: `signal(SIGCHLD,sighdr);` Now, the `sleep` will terminate as soon as the child exits.

Comment: We add the extra `waitpid` so that we _reap_ the child after the `kill`. (i.e. it does _not_ become a zombie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using SIGALRM?

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <signal.h>
  3 #include <unistd.h>
  4 
  5 pid_t pid;
  6 
  7 void handler(int signal)
  8 {
  9   kill(pid, SIGKILL);
 10 }
 11 
 12 int main(void)
 13 {
 14   signal(SIGALRM, handler);
 15 
 16   alarm(10);
 17 
 18   if(!(pid = fork())) {
 19     while(1) {
 20       // child will do something here
 21       sleep(2);
 22       puts("child working");
 23     }
 24   } else {
 25     // parent here
 26     puts("waiting for child");
 27     int status;
 28     waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
 29     puts("done waiting for child");
 30   }
 31
 32   return 0;
 33 }
```

Compile:

```
$ gcc alarm.c -o alarm && ./alarm
alarm.c: In function 'main':
alarm.c:28:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'waitpid' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
     ^
waiting for child
child working
child working
child working
child working
done waiting for child
```

Comment: Cramming `if(!(pid = fork()))` all into the `if` statement gains nothing over `pid = fork(); if (!pid)...`.  Saving lines of code is only good if you're the publisher of a textbook and saving a few pennies per copy printed helps pay for your swimming pool.  And using `sigaction()` instead of `signal()` provides portable behavior.

Comment: Good point. This is meant as demonstration code only, not for production. I even lazily omitted the #include <sys/wait.h> because I couldn’t be bothered to copy and paste again.